# Hot Meta Posts titles aren't spaced from vote totals if vote total is a three-digit number

Tags: bug, design, community-bulletin

Recently, a post with a three-digit vote score ended up on the Hot Meta Posts list on Stack Overflow. Due to its high vote score, it ended up just *barely* touching the post title link:

[image: 129Hurry, [sales] end soon]

Can extra space be added between the vote score and post title if the score is 100 or higher?

(This bug seems to have been introduced when the new Community Bulletin rolled out; a long time ago, with the older Community Bulletin, one of my posts ended up on Hot Meta Posts with 100+ score and it showed up fine, with enough space.)

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SO: [The Hot Meta Posts vote counter is too narrow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384507/4642212).